# How can i fix this in raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, google-oauth

This is the code:

```
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets ~/googleassistant/credentials.json \
--scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
--scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \
--save --headless
```

This is the error:
`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/pi/googleassistant/credentials.json'`

how can I fix it, thanks.

Comment: I try that what you say it ctually can’t work out. Im using the (env) pi@raspberrypi: ~ $ in this code.(python)

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory: `Is a directory: '/home/pi/googleassistant/credentials.json'\`

Maybe you have created a 'credentials.json' directory instead of making it a file? Or maybe you forgot a space between `.json` and  `\` ?